# I wanna leave my new 2-month old job. What valid reasons can I give to the interviewers?

Tags: interviewing, resignation

I work as a Software Engineer (programmer), kinda in a senior level but not in paper, like I still have a senior or supervisor.

There were multiple companies which got interested in me and they didn't seem interested at all to the reason why I'm looking for a new job even though I've been in my current job for only 2 months.

BUT there was one company that really caught me off guard when the interviewer asked me a couple of times the reason why I'm leaving my job.

Will saying ***I don't fit the company's culture suffice***?

I know saying `it's personal reasons` will get me more into trouble. Like the interviewer would ask more follow-up questions. I just wanna leave my job.

**REAL REASONS:**

1. I just wanna leave my job.
2. I can't handle my seemingly hot-headed lead.
3. I just don't meet the company's expectation.
4. Related to #2, just hours ago, the lead, while being disappointed with me, he said that I'm very well paid. (of course he knows my rate).

p.s. Current full-time job is merely a contractual, means it's like I'm working as a freelancer but in full-time.

Comment: Good idea. But I'm still afraid that won't work to other intimidating interviewers (like the CEOs) like the one I had just last week. But I'd love to use that, idc if they accept it or not. :D Thanks!

Comment: But what could be the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I be sincere - in an interview - about the reason for leaving my previous job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9312/should-i-be-sincere-in-an-interview-about-the-reason-for-leaving-my-previous)

Comment: If you are contractual you have a contract to fulfill.  Typically those have a termination date.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I can't handle my seemingly hot-headed lead.

If you can phrase this appropriately, then it is a valid reason. I think the general description would be something like `the job turned out to not be a good fit`. "Cultural" doesn't work here, see [this for reference](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/158261/new-on-job-uncomfortable-with-profanity).

It is important to gauge whether you have done your best to learn how to communicate with the lead. Two months at the job is not very much time to figure out communication and relationship. It is important because it might be a recurring problem if you don't learn how to resolve work conflicts.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere as i understand the story should go something like "I couldn't see eye to eye with manager on {technical or other issues} and after X months of trying to work it out, we decided to part ways". Does that seem reasonable?

Comment: I would not recommend speaking bad of your current manager in an interview. I would frame it in terms of organizational culture.  Some statement that doesn't reference you or the manager.  e.g. "My current job is is a high pressure environment where a lot of employees are hazed unnecessarily for missing unreasonable deadlines. I want to work in a positive and more respectful environment."

Comment: Employees are not machines/slaves, they can not be happy with a place/manager, and in fact the reason of many changes are managers. The fault is not necessarily in the employee lack of communication skills. Life is too short to work in places we do not like. Also "full-time" contractor is an HUGE red flag.

Comment: I'm kind of on the fence about this answer. I like it but at the same time I feel with him being there for only a few months that if he says he's not a good fit that it would be more negative than if he just simply said jcmack answer where he's just looking for a more stable position. That means he's doing well, but the workplace isn't looking to have him there for long term and he's looking for that.

Comment: @Dan that is why I suggest OP make sure they did their best to before to work things out leaving

Answer (score 6):

> BUT there was one company that really caught me off guard when the interviewer asked me a couple of times the reason why I'm leaving my job.
>
> Will saying I don't fit the company's culture suffice?

It's not uncommon to ask why someone is leaving their company after only 2 months. It's because 2 months is not enough time to assess and make an impact on your work culture. I recommend playing up the fact that you're on a contract and you're looking for either your next contract position (as expected of contractors) or looking for more stable employment.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the recommendation. I think this is a good answer too! :D I'll definitely use that when the follow-up question comes in like discussed in aaaa's answer.

Comment: it seems like a good pivot from "what was wrong" to "what I want better" + contract is an opp to not look like job-hopper

Answer (score -1):

In many countries there is the experimental period, where *both* parties can terminate the contract at will (typically six, can go up to nine months).

However, the experimental period is for salaried employees. Doing exit interviews for contractors, whilst not unheard of, is...strange. Even more for a resource that is still fitting in the culture and/or in the experimental period. I would refuse an exit interview solely on that basis.

Nevertheless, whilst the chosen question is the right answer, it fails to mention it is perfectly reasonable to:

. not liking a job;
   . the interview/job experience being a two way street.

You own them nothing, it is a business experience. Go for it and find someplace else more to your liking.