# Can I not list my current job on my resume?

Tags: new-job

Any kinds of comments are welcome, since this is an anonymous post. So a month ago, I posted here about leaving my 2-month old job for a better company. [I wanna leave my new 2-month old job. What valid reasons can I give to the interviewers?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/158827/i-wanna-leave-my-new-2-month-old-job-what-valid-reasons-can-i-give-to-the-inter)

I succeeded. I was able to leave the company and was able to land the "dream job". That dream job is what I have now, I'm working here for 2 weeks.

BUT, there's this another opportunity ‍♂️ I know, I hate myself for not being contented. When I landed the dream job above, I never opened any job posting sites, unsubscribed to email notifications, and whatnot - simply because I love my job. But this new opportunity could give me twice of what I'm having now. And this could give me an opportunity to permanently leave the side hustling (sideline jobs).

Anyways TL;DR: I'm planning to "lie" on my resume by not listing my current 2-weeks old job. I highly doubt they can find about this, because I never updated my profiles. I haven't got the "offer" but it's crazy that I'm already assuming that I will be able to pass the hiring process for this new opportunity.

Comment: What's wrong with the usual "don't lie" advice? And if they see you as someone who just jumps ship at first opportunity, well, it's an accurate description isn't it? And it is indeed a very strong warning.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that's it, and I guess I just wanted someone to somehow "support" me with this bad move that I have in mind.

Comment: I can share small anegdotal story with you, recently I was running recruitment for a company X, previously I worked with company Y where the loudly-fired ops person was fired, and they spend 4 months fixing his mess. The same person applied to company X, managed to charm way through interviews just to then for his name to pass my email list as a random CC. He obviously didn't get the job, and for his deception no one on this hiring committee will ever consider him for a job. And as this shows, the world is small, so lies eventually come out. He didn't disclose company Y obv.

Comment: This is an interesting story, Paul. Thanks for sharing this! I've never thought about it :) Although it seems impossible for the new company to discover that I have a 2-week old job, it's possible that they will do eventually. But the answer that I accepted is so so interesting that I will follow it - ie. be honest with the owner of the company (the new opportunity) and start from there if he's cool with it.

Comment: It's never impossible for lie to come to light, just varying degrees of unlikely. Assumption of never is what eventually gets you.

Comment: If you're perfectly content with the job you have now, why leave so soon?  Work towards a year and maybe another such opportunity will come about, then you'll decide whether it's worth leaving or not hopefully

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might start out as a "simple" lie-of-ommission, where you leave the company off your resume, however it's almost inevitable that at *some point* someone, whether it's in the hiring process or even after you've joined, is going to ask what you did during the two "missing" weeks, even if it's just casually. At that point you're going to have to *actually* lie.

Maybe it will never come up again, or maybe you'll run into someone you used to work with at the 2-week job in the course of your new one and it's all going to get a bit awkward to say the least. You'd be surprised how often that sort of thing seems to happen.

Let's be honest - an employment record for the last two jobs of 2 months and 2 weeks doesn't look good. You're going to have to be really convincing to dissuade someone from jumping straight to the common denominator in these jobs not working out being you and probably the best you can hope for is "will leave a person shaped hole in the wall the second a shiny new opportunity comes along" but that's a much better look than "lying liar that lies", I mean if nothing else you can give an honest answer to "why are you leaving after two weeks" during interviews

> Honestly I'm happy at my current role and I wasn't looking but when this opportunity arose I felt it was so special I had to give it a shot.

And I don't think that's too difficult to accept - I think many people would at least take a shot at something if it offered the opportunity to double their current wage, even if they were happy where they were.

That said I think if you *do* go for this one and you do get it you're going to need to be there for some time - two short spans can be potentially explained as a coincidence, three is a pattern that most sane hiring managers are going to be paying attention to.